# Center icon vertically and horizontally and text just above the div border

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I want the **sometext** to be just above the div border.

```css
.reg_form_fields_icon_box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: thin #dee5e7 solid;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon {
  margin: auto;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon .text_name {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="reg_form_fields_icon_box text-center">
  <div class="reg_form_fields_icon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></i>
    <div class="m-t-md text_name">
      <span>sometext</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: just like in the image]

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: can't you just some padding top or margin top in the element?

Comment: i can do.. but i don't want to do that. because if there may not be text below the icon then i have to adjust it again. so is there a way to do with provided code?

Comment: you can increase the line height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this `flexbox` itself and you don't need `calc` to set the positions - *position* it absolutely - so here is what I did:

1. You can make your `reg_form_fields_icon_box` a `flexbox` that is *vertically* and *horizontally* aligned.
2. Reset the `margin: auto` and set it to 100% `height` and `width` as well

   ```
   .reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Now position the `reg_form_fields_icon` *absolute*ly and align it to the *bottom* using this:

   ```
   .reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon .text_name {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
   }
   ```

See demo below:

```css
.reg_form_fields_icon_box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: thin #dee5e7 solid;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon {
  margin: auto;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon .text_name {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
/*ADDED THESE*/

.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon .text_name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="reg_form_fields_icon_box text-center">
  <div class="reg_form_fields_icon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></i>
    <div class="m-t-md text_name">
      <span>sometext</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution using flexbox:

```css
.reg_form_fields_icon_box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: thin #dee5e7 solid; 
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.reg_form_fields_icon_box .reg_form_fields_icon i {
  font-size: 20px;
  top:calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="reg_form_fields_icon_box text-center">
  <div class="reg_form_fields_icon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></i>
    <div class="m-t-md text_name">
      <span>sometext</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css:

```
div.reg_form_fields_icon_box {
    position: relative;
}

div.reg_form_fields_icon_box div.reg_form_fields_icon div.text_name{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```